# Is the Python Windows launcher (Python 3.3/PEP 397) backwards compatible?

Tags: python, windows

Is the new Windows launcher (interprets shebangs) in [Python 3.3.0](http://www.python.org/download/releases/3.3.0/) (courtesy [PEP 397](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/)) backwards compatible with all old Py 2.X interpreters?  From reading the PEP I can't quite tell for sure, and/or if I have to do anything special to get them to coexist.  The last update to the PEP is over a year old, versus the ~1 month old 3.3 release.

Comment: Are you worried about whether it breaks 2.x installations, or about whether it requires the 2.x to be new-ish and won't work with your old 2.4.1 or whatever? For the latter question, I know the answer is "yes". For the former, it's certainly _supposed_ to work the way you described in your own answer, but it was probably worth your testing it for yourself.

Comment: What do you mean by *backwards compatible* here?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost *whereas* I have an existing Py 2.x installation, *whereas* I install Py 3.3+ on top of it, I will be able to run my existing Python 2.x scripts (does not disturb the default interpreter).

Answer (score 1):

Recklessly gambling with my Windows' rats-nest of registry keys and environment variables reveals the answer:  **Yes.**

Installing Python 3.3.0 on top of an existing 2.x (2.7.3 in my case) installation effectively left everything as the status-quo.  Scripts are now launched by default through the `py.exe` launcher in `%systemroot%`, which, in absence of any directive to the contrary (via a shebang or command-line switch, a la `py -3 [myscript]`) uses the 2.x interpreter.